# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery when taking SUM of a Column returned by CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a problem with the following SQL query. While executing, it gives error:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>
> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

```
SELECT 
sum(case when DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO != null then (select PALLETNO_MASTER.PALLET_WEIGHT from PALLETNO_MASTER where DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO= PALLETNO_MASTER.PALLET_NO and DESP_SCANNING.REGION_ID = PALLETNO_MASTER.REGION_ID) else (select CARTONNO_MASTER.CARTON_WEIGHT from CARTONNO_MASTER where DESP_SCANNING.CARTON_NO = CARTONNO_MASTER.CARTON_NO and DESP_SCANNING.REGION_ID = CARTONNO_MASTER.REGION_ID) end) as totweight

FROM CUSTOMER_MASTER, DESP_SCANNING, CARRIER_MASTER, DC_MASTER

WHERE CARRIER_MASTER.CARRIER_CODE = DESP_SCANNING.CARRIER_CODE AND 

((DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO != null and DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO = (select PALLETNO_MASTER.PALLET_NO from PALLETNO_MASTER where DESP_SCANNING.REGION_ID = PALLETNO_MASTER.REGION_ID)) or(DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO = null and DESP_SCANNING.CARTON_NO = (select CARTONNO_MASTER.CARTON_NO from CARTONNO_MASTER where DESP_SCANNING.REGION_ID = CARTONNO_MASTER.REGION_ID))) AND

DESP_SCANNING.STATUS = 2 

group by DESP_SCANNING.DC_NO, DESP_SCANNING.POD_DATE, CUSTOMER_MASTER.CUS_NAME, CARRIER_MASTER.CARRIER_NAME, DESP_SCANNING.AWB_NO,DC_MASTER.DESP_END_DATE_TIME, DESP_SCANNING.SCAN_DATE, DC_MASTER.PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME

order by CARRIER_MASTER.CARRIER_NAME, DESP_SCANNING.POD_DATE
```

Error shows in this line:

```
sum(case when DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO != null then (select PALLETNO_MASTER. PALLET_WEIGHT from PALLETNO_MASTER where DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO= PALLETNO_MASTER.PALLET_NO and DESP_SCANNING.REGION_ID = PALLETNO_MASTER.REGION_ID) else (select CARTONNO_MASTER.CARTON_WEIGHT from CARTONNO_MASTER where DESP_SCANNING.CARTON_NO = CARTONNO_MASTER.CARTON_NO and DESP_SCANNING.REGION_ID = CARTONNO_MASTER.REGION_ID) end) as totweight,
```

So, what I can give instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to factor out the CASE ... construct (which has the subquery's that cause the error message) into the WHERE clause.

That is, first construct a single table that contains PALLET_WEIGHT or CARTON_WEIGHT as appropriate, in a single column, and do the SUM over that column.  Genre SELECT SUM(x) FROM (your big complicated SELECT here).

(I'm not guaranteeing that this will be possible.  It's just what I would try to do having read what the error message tells me.  Bigger product experts than me could possibly tell you my idea won't work either.)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code will help you:

```
select sum(x.totweight) as totweight
from (

select  
        CARRIER_MASTER.CARRIER_NAME, 
        DESP_SCANNING.POD_DATE,
        case when DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO != null then(
                      select  PALLETNO_MASTER.PALLET_WEIGHT
                      from    PALLETNO_MASTER
                      where   DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO = PALLETNO_MASTER.PALLET_NO
                              and DESP_SCANNING.REGION_ID = PALLETNO_MASTER.REGION_ID
                  )
             else(
                      select  CARTONNO_MASTER.CARTON_WEIGHT
                      from    CARTONNO_MASTER
                      where   DESP_SCANNING.CARTON_NO = CARTONNO_MASTER.CARTON_NO
                              and DESP_SCANNING.REGION_ID = CARTONNO_MASTER.REGION_ID
                  )
        end as totweight
from    CUSTOMER_MASTER,
        DESP_SCANNING,
        CARRIER_MASTER,
        DC_MASTER
where   CARRIER_MASTER.CARRIER_CODE = DESP_SCANNING.CARRIER_CODE
        and (
            (
                DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO != null
                and DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO = (
                    select  PALLETNO_MASTER.PALLET_NO
                    from    PALLETNO_MASTER
                    where   DESP_SCANNING.REGION_ID = PALLETNO_MASTER.REGION_ID
                )
            )
            or (
                DESP_SCANNING.PALLET_NO = null
                and DESP_SCANNING.CARTON_NO = (
                    select  CARTONNO_MASTER.CARTON_NO
                    from    CARTONNO_MASTER
                    where   DESP_SCANNING.REGION_ID = CARTONNO_MASTER.REGION_ID
                )
            )
        )
        and DESP_SCANNING.status = 2
group by    DESP_SCANNING.DC_NO,
            DESP_SCANNING.POD_DATE,
            CUSTOMER_MASTER.CUS_NAME,
            CARRIER_MASTER.CARRIER_NAME,
            DESP_SCANNING.AWB_NO,
            DC_MASTER.DESP_END_DATE_TIME,
            DESP_SCANNING.SCAN_DATE,
            DC_MASTER.PSR_LOAD_DATE_TIME
) x
order by x.CARRIER_NAME, x.POD_DATE
```